# Differences between events and semaphores

Tags: c, events, operating-system, semaphore

I already searched for this subject but couldn't understand it very well. What are the main differences between events and semaphores?

Comment: Googling the title gives: 'About 231,000 results'.  DCV.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a Google-slave request for a unique assignment answer.

Answer (score 3):

An event generally has only two states, unsignaled or signaled. A semaphore has a count, and is considered unsignaled if the count is zero, and signaled if the count is not zero. In the case of Windows, ReleaseSemaphore() increments a semaphore count, and WaitForSingleObject(...) with a handle of a semaphore will wait (unless the timeout parameter is set to zero) for a non-zero count, then decrement the count before returning.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need do know it in a specific context? That would help to make it better understandable.

Typically a semaphore is some token that must be obtained to execute an action, e.g. lock on an execution unit that is protected from concurrent access.

Events are functions in a message/subscriber pattern.

So they are somewhat related but not even comparable.

A typical confusing/complex scenario that you may face is that one event triggers two different subscribers, that than want simultaneous access to some resource. They should request for a semaphore token and release it after use to let the other subscriber have a go.